# Why are signals reflected from an antennas dish as opposed to being absorbed?

Tags: antenna, ground, radio, electromagnetic, radiation

I am trying to learn in the area of electromagnetic noise ect.

I see online that a Faraday cage can work without been contected to ground (like the ones found on radio PCBs.) It sort of makes sense to me since the metal itself can just create an opposing field when the incoming electromagnetic wave hits.

Going of that same principle, how can the metal dish used on lots of antennas (like the Sky ones,) reflect the signals towards the center part, as opposed to just absorbing? I understand it is far from a full enclosure for an actuall Faraday cage, but I would have still thought the incoming waves would be absorbed. Similar to my curiosity of the GPS ground plane.

Comment: Same way you see your reflection in a mirror: pick a material (such as the metal in your mirror) that is reflective.

Answer (score 2):

Metals have high concentrations of mobile carriers (electrons). This allows them to, as you say, "create an opposing field when the incoming electromagnetic wave hits". That opposing field is the source of the reflected wave.

A metal object is reflective whether it's in the shape of a box (as in a typical Faraday cage) or of a dish.

Comment: Thank you. And so why are faraday cages use to prevent noise spreading in/out, if say for example an incoming wave was absorbed, and re emitted as mentioned, would this not also be emitted inside the cage, redering it pointless?

Comment: @Georgekirby, if a wave impinges on a metal box (a Faraday cage) from the outide, the signal is reflected back to the outside of the box, not re-emitted to the interior of the box. The wall of the box has to be thick enough (more than a few times the skin depth for that material and the signal's frequency) so that the currents caused by the wave are (effectively) all on the outer surface, and don't extend through the entirety of the metal wall.

Answer (score 1):

The waves come in, currents get induced in the metal dish that mirror the incoming wave, the wave is retransmitted as if it’s reflected.  Because the metal dish is a really good conductor, the reflected wave is a lot like the incoming wave, and no power is lost.  To be “absorbed”, the wave has to induce currents in some lossy part, like a resistor or the input of an amplifier.

Answer (score 1):

The key is how much secondary magnetic field is created by the induction.

If equal in proportion to the incident field, the incident and reflected fields sum to zero at the surface, no energy is absorbed, all is reflected.  For the near-field case, this effectively reduces the volume of the source field (inductance of the source coil decreases); for the far-field case, the reflected magnetic field gives rise to electric field alternately, in the usual way, and the propagating wave is simply reflected with respect to the surface.

The same is true of the electric field component, of course, and both [E and H reflection] must be true to reflect propagating EM waves.

If the return is slightly less, then it is due to the material's resistance: some EMF is lost to V = IR, and the remaining EMF is reflected.  Good metals are 99%+ mirrors at most frequencies (assuming several skin depths of material at the test frequency), and most (all?) metals are better than 80 or 90% reflective.

If no magnetic field is reflected at all, that means no current flow -- infinite resistance, an insulator.  In this case, the incident field passes straight on through.

Somewhere inbetween, there exists a case where neither transmission nor reflection occurs.  (Mind, transmission can be made arbitrarily close to zero by making the material ever thicker, but reflection is characteristic.)  The impedance of such material matches the impedance of free space.  That is, field is absorbed exactly in proportion to the amount of field that propagates normally -- which is to say, the field "felt" by one region of space, by the next adjacent region.  As the wave enters such a material, it doesn't "know" that anything has changed, the ratio of E/H remains the same, but it's decaying with distance, rather than propagating onward.  (Whether absorption happens within many wavelengths, or a tiny fraction, doesn't really matter -- again, thickness is a variable, but reflection is characteristic.)

Pure bulk metals happen to be quite far from the ideal absorber case.  Even familiar "black" materials still have a sheen to them: consider the glint of glossy black paint, or the metallic luster of graphite; they might only reflect 10%, or 1%, but a smooth surface still gives a detectable specular reflection.  Few materials absorb perfectly, and those that do must balance the reflection of both electric and magnetic fields.  (We might suppose magnetite is good at absorbing magnetic fields, but perhaps it is, in a sense, too "dense" to perfectly absorb electric fields, and so some wave energy is still reflected.)  Most materials achieve very low reflection rates by making a convoluted, frustrated path for waves to follow: reflecting inward, deeper into the bulk, losing energy with each reflection.  Consider carbon black, nano-black materials like Vanta, or the old trick of making an optical trap by stacking otherwise-shiny razor blades (light spirals inward between acute angles, until eventually being dissipated as heat).

Contrast these materials and structures, with the design of a Faraday shield, or antenna dish (or the antenna elements themselves, for that matter).  We use bulk metals, of high conductivity (especially aluminum and copper), and smooth shape, so that the wave path is direct, straightforward, and indeed made to constructively interfere at the antenna feedpoint (hence the high gain of dish-type antennas).

We could still make a dish antenna with lossy materials, but to reflect waves, we depend upon whatever mismatch they have, and overall antenna gain suffers.  There are still practical cases for this: at x-ray wavelengths, *nothing* is a good mirror, and some very peculiar designs (grazing angle optics) are used to mitigate the loss.  Ground-wave reflection at SW and below, is also a useful instance.  Sky-wave reflection too, for that matter: the ionosphere isn't particularly conductive, really, it's just *big*.

Comment: Many thanks. It helps alot but I still have a couple questions since im not at a level to intuitively understand your reply. 1) when you said that the materials that have an infinite resistance don’t reflect (since they can’t make the feild I assume) , and that the wave goes past, how is that different to when you say the material is at impedance of space?(if it just “decays with distance “) 2)If the signals on a good conductor are re transmitted, how does a faraday cage prevent incoming waves on a pcb if the waves would be retransmitted in all directions? Is this to do with ground? Thanks :)

Comment: 1. Infinite resistance means zero reflected magnetic field. Optimal resistance means magnetic field reflected exactly in proportion to incident (in such a way that the wave is fully absorbed; roughly speaking, the reflection is half the incident value, but there is more to it than magnetism, and I must be intentionally vague here to avoid going into field analysis). Note that "goes past" == transparent, no impact on the propagating wave, "decays with distance" == absorbed as the wave goes through the material. 2. Waves are retransmitted away from the surface, not through it.

Comment: Many thanks again that definitely helps alot, so if im correct here, if the wave is absorbed could this be used as a receiving antenna ? So the material of the antenna has to have an impedance of free space at the certain frequencies? And as for point 2) why is this? How does the metal know not to retransmit in the direction away from the incoming signals? Thanks

Comment: If the wave is absorbed *inside the material*, how could it be used as a receiving antenna (passing along the signal to a circuit)? The signal ceases to exist. | The metal retransmits in all directions, more or less (see: diffraction model of reflection). That includes directions into the material itself, which, as before, don't penetrate the material. Thus a circuit on one side is shielded from whatever is on the other side.

Comment: Thankyou, so does it just get absorbed as heat then? And so what would the impedance of a metal antenna need to be in order to absorb the waves as electricity? (Ik the feedpoint is usually designed to be 50ohm, but i mean the actual metal) . And so why does it not penetrate the metal to get to the other side like you say?

Comment: I posted this partly as a separate question if that helps